Fix a portion of LaTeX to repeat on every slide of a Beamer presentation
I would like to make a Beamer presentation, in which the same fixed document appears on the left half of every slide.  On the right half, the slides may change as you progress through the presentation.  Here is an attempt to render what I have in mind.
This image shows the first frame -- it doesn't have to look exactly like this, but hopefully this gives the idea of a fixed document on the left, and "exposition" document on the right.

The next frame looks like this, with the fixed frame unchanged, although perhaps with annotation.

It would be especially nice to do the highlighting thing too, but that would just be extra.
As a note, this would not be for a talk or presentation -- I would be using these slides for teaching.  The intent is that the left-hand fixed document to be a dense and complicated thing, like a long proof of a theorem for example.  The right-hand "exposition" document would be identifying some small part and explaining what is happening there.
Ideally, the fixed doc can eventually be changed.  And there could be any number of exposition documents for a given fixed doc.
I can see that one possibility would be to render the fixed frame and then include it in a multicolumn environment or something like that.  This makes it hard to edit the fixed doc if I later change my mind, but it's one solution.  I'm also not entirely sure how I would then put annotations on the document, from one slide to the next.
So I'm wondering if there is a better and more flexible solution than that.  Any help or advice about how to make this would be appreciated, thanks!
These frames were created with the code
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetheme{Goettingen}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\title[MathReason] %optional
{Mathematical Reasoning}
\subtitle{Lesson 0001: Origins of Proof}
\author[] % (optional)
{}

\institute[] % (optional)
{
  
}

\date[] % (optional)
{\today}

% Use a simple TikZ graphic to show where the logo is positioned
\logo{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,color=white] at (0,0) {$\forall x$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
%Highlighting text

\begin{frame}{Example Fixed Frame}
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Example Exposition Frame, 1}
    In the frame to the left, the first sentence starts with ``Lorem''.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Example Exposition Frame, 2}
    The second sentence ends in ``felis''.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

But this shouldn't be too important since I'm not concerned about getting a particular Beamer theme or color.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

You could abuse note pages for this. This is just a quick proof on concept, you could adjust the layout of the note page to include a sidebar, title etc if needed.
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\setbeamertemplate{note page}{\vskip-2cm\vfil\insertnote}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \alert<1>{First sentence.} \alert<2>{Second sentence.} \alert<3>{Third sentence.}
  
  \note<1>{Special stuff about first sentence}
  \note<2>{Special stuff about second sentence}
  \note<3>{Special stuff about third sentence}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Or you could use columns:
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \alert<1>{First sentence.} \alert<2>{Second sentence.} \alert<3>{Third sentence.}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \only<1>{Special stuff about first sentence}%
    \only<2>{Special stuff about second sentence}%
    \only<3>{Special stuff about third sentence}%
  \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}



That actually might be better than what I was thinking!  I didn't really need a full frame on each side, all that matters is the fixed/exposition thing.  Thanks!

@Addem You're welcome!
